# Where can I buy Intel Atom processor

Tags: processor

I want to buy Intel Atom C2550 but could not find it online.

anyone knows where I can buy one?

Thanks

Comment: The Atom C2550 (Avoton) is a BGA packaged CPU, which means retailers typically do not sell them individually, instead, they are sold pre-attached to motherboards. For example, Newegg stocks [this board](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16813157419) offered by ASRock and [here](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Atom/X10/A1SAi-2550F.cfm) is another option offered by SuperMicro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Atom series of CPUs isn't available in socketed form.  Instead, the CPUs are designed to be soldered onto a mainboard, with the combined CPU/board sold to end users or built into a finished product.

The best way to get a C2550 is to decide if you'd rather have a CPU/mainboard combo or a pre-built computer, and pick something that best meets your needs.